# Google TV stream Protocls Android

Tags: android, streaming, protocols, google-tv

I am working on an application for google tv with Visio device , i want to know which streaming protocols are avalable for google tv out of these. Can any body give me the reference along with the reply. 
HTTP, RTMP, PNM, RTSP, MMS, RTSPU, RTSPT, MMSU, MMST.

Please help any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is going to be your best bet on Vizio wrt ease of setup and development. You can use VLC to experiment with different stream proto's. The thing you should pay close attention to is what codec you are transmitting your media in - https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats